# Popup positioning in wpf using c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, popup

I have placed a popup on a button mouseover.Each time when i  mouse over that button my custom designed popup is being showed perfectly.Butit doesn't point the button perfectly. How to do so ..?
Now my popup looks like

[image]

**I want that arrow mark to point that help button** How to acheive it..

Here is my code for the button and popup in xaml

```
<telerik:RadButton Name="btnH" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="444,56,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                 Width="23" Height="23" BorderThickness="6" BorderBrush="#4E4E4E">
            <Image Source="Images/help.png" />
            <telerik:RadButton.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard TargetName="TooltipPopup" TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames  FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00"  Value="True" />
                                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
```

and below is the custom usercontrol xaml which amn calling in popup

```
<UserControl
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" x:Class="WPFTest.UCToolTip" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Height="231.493" Width="362.075"
         Background="Transparent"  >
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
                 <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextDecorations" Value="{x:Null}" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid Margin="10,0,0,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Background="red" Margin="0,0,182,133">            

    </Grid>
    <Polygon
    Points="0.5,0 15,0, 0,30" Stroke="Orange" Fill="Orange" Margin="0,98,0,101" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: hey, did the answer helped..or you still getting some problem?

Answer (score 4):

use this style for your `Popup`:

```
<Style TargetType="Popup">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsOpen" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="PlacementTarget" Value="{Binding ElementName=btnH }" />
                        <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Top" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalOffset" Value="-5" />
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalOffset" Value="5" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that Kylo pointed you to the right answer. If you get rid of the margin in the usercontrol it should work.

This is the code for the usercontrol.

```
<UserControl
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" x:Class="WpfTest.UCToolTip" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Height="130" Width="180"
         Background="Transparent"  >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextDecorations" Value="{x:Null}" />
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid Margin="10,0,0,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Background="red" Margin="0,0,0,32">

        </Grid>
        <Polygon Points="0.5,0 15,0, 0,30" Stroke="Orange" Fill="Orange" Margin="0,98,0,0" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the code for the window.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Popup">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsOpen" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="PlacementTarget" Value="{Binding ElementName=btnH }" />
                    <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Top" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalOffset" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalOffset" Value="145" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>        
    </Window.Resources>    
    <Grid>
        <telerik:RadButton Name="btnH" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="300,175,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                 Width="50" Height="23" BorderThickness="6" BorderBrush="#4E4E4E">
            <Image Source="Images/help.png" />
            <telerik:RadButton.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard TargetName="TooltipPopup" TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames  FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00"  Value="True" />
                            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>

                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard TargetName="TooltipPopup" TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames  FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00"  Value="False" />
                            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </telerik:RadButton.Triggers>

        </telerik:RadButton>

        <Popup x:Name="TooltipPopup" AllowsTransparency="True">
            <StackPanel>
                <uc:UCToolTip></uc:UCToolTip>
            </StackPanel>
        </Popup>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/JohanLarsson/Gu.Wpf.Geometry) is a small library with balloons for WPF that I think does what you want.

Usage:

```
<geometry:Balloon ConnectorAngle="25"
                  CornerRadius="15"
                  PlacementOptions="Bottom, Center"
                  PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=Target}">
     <!--  content here  -->
</geometry:Balloon>
```